# Remove JSX data attribute from tag in production

Tags: reactjs, typescript

If I have the following code:

`<Component data-testid="foo">Element to Test</Component>`

How can I remove the `data-testid` attribute in production.

Babel has this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-react-remove-properties. Is there something similar I can do with TypeScript compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel 7 allows you to transform typescript. Here is [a link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11441) to the discussion.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of that. Unfortunately, we're using Create-React-App which doesn't allow for TypeScript compile via babel... so we're using create-react-app-typescript.